# Display images from firebase storage in html img tags

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm attempting to display an image from firebase into html `img` tags, but it fails to retrieve the image.

Javascript code:

```js
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
var spaceRef = storageRef.child('images/photo_1.png');
var path = spaceRef.fullPath;
var gsReference = storage.refFromURL('gs://test.appspot.com')

storageRef.child('images/photo_1.png').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  var test = url;
}).catch(function(error) {

});
```

html code:

```
<img src="test" height="125" width="50"/>
```

Comment: Your img src attribute contains the string `"test"` as URL, it doesn't contain the content of the test variable

Comment: downloadUrl no longer exists on task.snapshot.downloadUrl

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you have the `test` variable, you need to set the image's src to it using a script.

Something like this:

```js
//var storage    = firebase.storage();
//var storageRef = storage.ref();
//var spaceRef = storageRef.child('images/photo_1.png');
//
//storageRef.child('images/photo_1.png').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
//
//
//  var test = url;
//  add this line here:
//  document.querySelector('img').src = test;
//
//}).catch(function(error) {
//
//});
//
var test = 'firebase_url';

document.querySelector('img').src = test;
```

```html
<img height="125" width="50"/>
```

Comment: I wonder if those tokens at the end of download URL are safe to be shown to clients ?? Is it okay?

Answer (score 9):

The bellow two lines which is commented are not required, I have tested. it is working fine.

```
//var path = spaceRef.fullPath;
//var gsReference = storage.refFromURL('gs://test.appspot.com')

    <script>
     function showimage() {



         var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
         var spaceRef = storageRef.child('sweet_gift/vytcdc.png');
         storageRef.child('sweet_gift/vytcdc.png').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
             var test = url;
             alert(url);
             document.querySelector('img').src = test;

         }).catch(function(error) {

         });


     }
    </script>
    <input type="button" value ="view Image" id="viewbtn" onclick="showimage();">
    <img src="test" height="125px" width="200px"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a neat way to load the images if you know the filenames in advance:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{{BUCKET}}/o/images%2{{FILENAME}}?alt=media
```

Remove the ?alt=media to get some metadata.

Comment: this doesnt work for storages behind authentication. You would need a token and append it to the urlparams with &token=...

Answer (score 4):

try this :-)

```js
//var storage    = firebase.storage();
//var storageRef = storage.ref();
//var spaceRef = storageRef.child('images/photo_1.png');
//
//storageRef.child('images/photo_1.png').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
//
//
//  var test = url;
//  add this line here:
//  document.getElementById("your_img_id").src = test;
//
//}).catch(function(error) {
//
//});
//
```

```html
<img height="125" width="50" id="your_img_id" src=""/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
           var uploader=document.getElementById('uploader'),
           fileButton=document.getElementById('fileButton');

           fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(e) {

           var file=e.target.files[0];

           var storageRef=firebase.storage().ref("'/images/'"+file.name);


            var task=storageRef.put(file);

            task.on('state_changed',

            function progress(snapshot){
            var percentage=( snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes )*100;
            uploader.value=percentage;
            if (percentage==100){
            alert("file uploaded Successfully");
            }
            },
            function error(err){

            },
            function complete(){

                 var text1=document.getElementById('text3');
                 var text7=document.getElementById('text4');
                 var text8=document.getElementById('text5');
                 var text9=document.getElementById('text6');

                var downloadURL =task.snapshot.downloadURL; 
                var postkey=firebase.database().ref('data-modeling/').push();
                var text2=text1.value;
                postkey.child("Name").set(text2);
                var texta=text7.value;
                postkey.child("Address").set(texta);
                var textb=text8.value;
                postkey.child("Age").set(textb);
                var textc=text9.value;
                postkey.child("PhoneNo").set(textc);
                postkey.child("url").set(downloadURL)
                alert('successful Submit');




             });

            }


        );
```

Comment: Hi, and very Welcome to StackOverflow! A tips when posting answers is to include some text explaining your code examples. That will help the person who asked the question, and also people viewing your answer in the future to understand what your answer is doing. Thanks for contributing to the community!

Answer (score 0):

This is a well-tested code. it is working fine. just follow these steps.

html code:

```
<img id="myImgId" src="" height="125" width="50"/>
```

Add config Information here

```
  con = {
        "apiKey": "your key",
        "authDomain": "example.firebaseapp.com",
        "databaseURL": "https://example.firebaseio.com/",
        "projectId": "example",
        "storageBucket": "example.appspot.com",
        "messagingSenderId": "id"
    };
```

Initialize firebase using this

```
firebase.initializeApp(con);
```

Create a reference with an initial file path and name

```
var storage = firebase.storage();
var storageRef = storage.ref();
//urll is the url for image
storageRef.child(urll).getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  // Or inserted into an <img> element:
  var img = document.getElementById('myImgId');
  img.src = url;
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle any errors
});
```