# how to display firebase storage img

Tags: firebase

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452633/display-images-from-firebase-storage-in-html-img-tags)

After you have a URL for example:

```
http://storage.googleapis.com/example-bda7b.appspot.com/images/someone-Lopez.jpg
```

You would still need to run `getDownloadURL`, something like this:

```
storageRef.child(urll).getDownloadURL()
```

This seems counter productive to me, if you already have the image storage url, why need to run getdownload url and wait for a response?

I've set my storage to public.  How would I be able to execute something like (in react):

```
  <img
    alt={props.data.last}
    className="rounded-circle"
    src={http://storage.googleapis.com/example-bda7b.appspot.com/images/someone-Lopez.jpg}
  />
```

Is something like the above example even possible? or
var storage = firebase.storage();
var pathReference = storage.ref('images/stars.jpg');

```
  <img
    alt={props.data.last}
    className="rounded-circle"
    src={pathReference}
  />
```

Firebase gives this example in the documentations but doesn't actually give any ideas of how to incorporate it.

```
// Create a reference with an initial file path and name
var storage = firebase.storage();
var pathReference = storage.ref('images/stars.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you to show image

```
<script>
function showimage() {
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    var spaceRef = storageRef.child('sweet_gift/vytcdc.png');
    storageRef.child('images/stars.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
        var test = url;
        alert(url);
        document.querySelector('img').src = test;
    }).catch(function(error) {
    });
}
</script>
<input type="button" value ="view Image" id="viewbtn" onclick="showimage();">
<img src="test" height="125px" width="200px"/>
```

if you try to open image with this [link](http://storage.googleapis.com/example-bda7b.appspot.com/images/someone-Lopez.jpg) it won't open instead it will provide you json data. You have to provide the downloadTokens of image then it will show. that's why you have to perform the `getDownloadUrl()` which will generate proper url of image with downloadTokens and alt.

You can check the alert you see full url.

Comment: But no token is needed, the storage is set to public.  What's the point of getting a token if I already have the direct link and the storage is set to public?  That is where I'm wondering why do you need to getDownloadURL when I already have a path?